# How to show errors, notices and warnings

Tags: php

I'm using **`UniServer Zero`** as PHP server but i wonder where to edit in `php.ini` or wherever in order to show up any errors, notices or warnings so that i make sure my code is working fine.

for example, I've made `index.php` file with the following code

```
<?PHP
$a = split(" ", "a b c");print_r($a);
?>
```

I'm pretty sure this must gives me at least `**Notice**` that `split` method has been `deprecated` .. am i right?! but it did not show anything just blank page.

Also this wrongly code

```
echo date("F j, Y", 1234567890, "something makes it wrong");
```

should gives me `**warning**` that `date()` expects at most 2 parameters but it only gives me blank page!

show up errors, notices and warnings will helps me a lot as student so how can i do it ?

*Note* : My **`UniServer Zero`** version 12.1.1 is using `PHP 7.0`

Comment: check this out: http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: Yes @TheCodesee , this one was very helpful , I've found `display_errors` set to OFF

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE ); // That does all you want.
```